# Comparing two PDF files programmatically

Tags: 2010, web-part

Is there any way by which I can compare two PDF files programmatically?

I have to create a new WebPart which takes two PDF files as its inputs and compares them.

I searched for the solution but it mostly suggests third party solutions. But I want to achieve this with a custom coded WebPart..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Split your file data string into words and then compare both file string.

i.e.

If you split your files into words, you may be able to use something like:

```
Dim str1 = New String() {"I", "love", "NY"}
Dim str2 = New String() {"I", "NY"}
Dim Diff = str1.Where(Function(x) Not str2.Contains(x)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, depending on the size of PDF files, you should consider delegating the task to a timer job (maybe a work item job).
The best option I can see would be to:

1. Compare file size. If not the same --> you immediately have the result.
2. Compute a hash for each file, and then compare hash. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318087/calculate-the-hash-of-the-contents-of-a-file-in-c for a code sample.